# How to read input from both a file and from user input C++

Tags: c++, file, input, user-input

I'm writing a program that needs to read input both from a file and from user input. For example, I will need the input from a user for example a password, and then check if the password is correct by comparing it with a password from a file. After that, I want to ask for more user input again and so on. I wonder if there is any way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Thanks for the comments to let me know that I should put in some code. This is my first time here so I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

string pass;
string userpass;

void getPassword()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    freopen("PASS.TXT", "r", stdin);
    cin >> pass;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter your password: ";
    cin >> userpass;
    getPassword();
    if (userpass == pass)
    {
        char yes;
        cout << "Correct password!\nType \"Y\" to continue... ";
        /*
        cin >> yes;
        if (yes == 'Y')
        {
            cout << "Do something here";
        }
        */
        // Now I need to get user to type "Y"
        // but if I use cin then it will continue
        // to get input from the file
    }
    else
    {
        cout <<"\nWrong password...";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Notice how all the operations you specify are *sequential*, which means you can do one operation after another in your code as well. As in: Ask user for input; Then check file; Then ask user for more input; ...

Comment: Hopefully you already know about `std::cin`, but you may be interested in the [basic_ifstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) for reading from files. Very similar interface but it reads from a file instead of standard input.

Comment: ***I wonder if there is any way to do this?*** `c++` would be a very useless language if it would not be possible.

Comment: Do you know how to write code to read a file? Do you know how to write code to receive input from the user? which part of this problem is difficult?

Comment: I recommend you split up many of these operations into their own function and test and solve them separately.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I do know how to use std::cin, and I know how to read input from a file using freopen(), but I can't use both of these one after the other. (I think the problem is that I don't know how to close the file after open it)

Comment: ***I don't know how to close the file*** You usually don't have to do that. However the member function to close a file is called close(). [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/close](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/close)

Comment: [Here's a list of good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/440558). Please invest in a couple of beginners books. They should have all the information you need on how work with files.

Comment: `ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);` and `freopen("PASS.TXT", "r", stdin);` I would not use either of these. Instead see the example at the bottom of this on how to use ifstream: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream)

Comment: As for your current code, the main problem is `freopen("PASS.TXT", "r", stdin);`. This will permanently redirect all input from standard input to be read from the file. From that point onward you can never read input from the user again, only from the file `PASS.TXT`.

Comment: Ohh so there's no way to use this? I didn't know how to use anything else because that's what I was taught at school. I guess now I will learn to use ifstream. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::cin` [from the `iostream` library] for getting the user's input, and use `std::ifstream` [from the `fstream` library] to read a file. Then, you can turn the buffer's contents into a string  [from the `string` library] using an sstream [from the `sstream` library] and then iterate through the file's contents and checking if they are the same as the passwords contents, excluding newlines of course, and then I close the file in the function. I optionally added `std::cout` to print out something. I wrapped the input in a while loop to make it repeat infinitely until the user gets the correct password, if they do i just run `break` to break the while loop. `freopen` isnt that good of an idea if you are going to capture user input.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

bool check_password(std::string password) {
   std::ifstream password_file("password.txt");
   std::ostringstream string_stream;
   string_stream << password_file.rdbuf();
   std::string file_password = string_stream.str();
   bool correct_password = true;
   for(int i = 0; i < file_password.size(); i++) {
      if(file_password[i] !=  password[i] && file_password[i] != '\n') {
         correct_password = false;
         break;
      }
   }
   password_file.close();
   return correct_password;
}

int main() {
   while(true) {
      std::cout << "Please type in your password." << std::endl;
      std::string password;
      std::cin >> password;
      std::cout << "Checking..." << std::endl;
      if(check_password(password)) {
         std::cout << "Correct password!" << std::endl;
         break;
      }
      std::cout << "Incorrect password." << std::endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It kinda worked, but do I have to do the for loop to compare the strings? Is there another way around this? And I assume that if there are multiple strings in the text file then all of them will be considered as one string with "\n" between the different strings in the files?

Comment: There is probably a function that gets the contents of the file and ignores newlines, but i just used a for loop for convenience purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The way to deal with files is to use cin to have an input data and
std::ifstream class that is used to open files for reading and
ifstream::operator>>() to read the data from the file stream.

example:

```cpp
std::string input;

std::cin >> input;

std::ifstream file;

file.open("file.txt", std::ifsream::in);

std::string password;

file >> password;

if (password == input)
//TODO

else
//Incorrect password
```

Comment: Also dont forget to close the file.

Comment: `std::ifstream` will auto close when the instance goes out of scope.

Comment: Do I have to import any libraries as when I try it it give me some errors?

Comment: `#include <fstream>` in addition to the ones you should already be using.

Comment: yeah The destructor itself invokes the close function but still, it is good practice to invoke ifstrea::close() by yourself